# Why is flask jsonify returning unidentified?

Tags: flask, fetch, jsonify

I am using fetch on the frontend to send data to my flask backend in order to make a movie seat booking. The whole process works fine until the client awaits the response, which is "undefined" . So , basically the database saves the data , the only problem is the response which is sent to the client. I used jsonify which usually works fine. Can anybody tell me what I am missing? Thanks in advance.

Here is the JS code :

```
function sendReservationToServer() {

    const selectedSeats = sessionStorage.getItem('selectedSeats')
    const reservation = { userId, selectedSeats, showTimeId, movieHallId }
    fetch('/bookSeats', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(reservation)
    }).then(response => {
        response.json()
    }).then(data => {
        theatreHall.innerHTML = `${data} <br> <a href='/home'>Back to main menu</a>`
        console.log(`${data}`)
    }).catch(err => infoMsg.textContent = err)
    sessionStorage.clear()
}
```

And this is the flask controller which handles the request:

```
@app.route("/bookSeats", methods=["POST"])
def book_seats():
    selected_seats = request.json
    user_id = selected_seats.get('userId')
    seats = json.loads(selected_seats.get('selectedSeats'))
    movie_hall_id = selected_seats.get('movieHallId')
    seat_ids = []
    showtime_id = selected_seats.get('showTimeId')
    for seat in seats:
        seat_ids.append(db.session.query(Seat).filter(
            Seat.seat_number == seat).filter(Seat.movie_hall_id == movie_hall_id).all()[0].stid)
    for seat in seat_ids:
        reserved_seat = ReservedSeat(
            seat_id=seat, show_time=showtime_id, user=user_id)
        db.session.add(reserved_seat)
        db.session.commit()
    reservation = Reservation(
        user=user_id, show_time=showtime_id, number_of_tickets=len(seat_ids))
    db.session.add(reservation)
    db.session.commit()
    message = f'{seats} booked successfully'
    return jsonify(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

`data` is undefined because the first `then` does not return anything. Either make it return `response.json()` or move everything in the second `then` to the first and replace `data` with `response.json()`.

Comment: You are right. It didn't return anything because the response.json was {response.json} . When I removed the {} it worked. Thanks for the feedback